# In the topology,dist(x,A)=d(x,y)

Tags: metric-spaces

Giving the example of a set A  ⊂  X and a point x ∈ X such that dist(x,A)=d(x,y) for :

1) all y ∈ A

2)a single point y ∈ A

3)exactly 3 points y ∈ A

Does anybody who someone to giving the example to over writing instances and draw pictures ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

We shall consider subsets of the plane $X=\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the standard metric.

1)  $A$ is a one-point set and $x$ is an arbitrary point or $A$ is a circle and $x$  is its center.

2) $A$ is a convex closed set (for instance, a disk or a straight line) and $x$ is an arbitrary point.

3) $A$ is a triangle and $x$ is the center of its incircle.

At the picture the point $x$ is red, the set $A$ is grey, and the subset of points of $A$ which are closest to $x$ is black.

[image]

Comment: Could you giving the example for 1,2 and 3 like drawing a picture ?

Comment: Thank you so much!